# Why can't install tensorflow version below 2.12?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

i want to use tensorflow - gpu, but i'm having some issues.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.10 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.10

I tried to install tensorflow==2.10, but i'm recieving these errors

Comment: Are you using python 3.11? Tensorflow 2.10 supports 3.7-3.10 (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.10.0/))

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) to install the specific tensorflow version compatible to which python version.
[image]

If you want to install tensorflow with GPU support in Win OS, please be sure to install `tensorflow 2.10 or below version` which is compatible with `python 3.7 to 3.10` because CUDA build is not supported for Windows in Tensorflow 2.11.

You can refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) link to install tensorflow with GPU by following all the Hardware/Software requirements and mentioned step by step instructions.